# Duplicate parameter string in URL

Tags: php, html, nginx

I have made a small website using PHP/MySQL

I have placed parameters & values into the hyperlinks to load dynamic content, however, when user click on the hyperlink the query string is duplicated in the browser window.

eg:

`<a href="mypage.php?id=123">MyLink</a>`

the web browsers load:

```
www.mysite.com/mypage.php?id=123?id=123
```

I'm sure it is something easy & simply, but after couple of hours on Google I can't find where I have gone wrong

Please help, loosing my sanity here

---

Hey all,

I was hopping this might be a simple attribute problem.

I have a MySQL DB with the usual fields...

- Public_ID [integer]
- Title [VARCHAR]
- PostDate [VARCHAR]
- IntroText [TEXT]
- BodyText [TEXT]
- etc...

Collation set to "utf8_general_ci"

I use PHP:

```
$QueryResult =  mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Public_ID, Title, Body, PostDate, Author, TopicID FROM news ORDER BY PostDate DESC");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($QueryResult)){

   echo "<div class=\"news_item\">
    <a href=\"article.php?sid".$result['Public_ID']."\">
        <span>
<em>".strip_tags(stripslashes($result['Title']))."</em>
<p>".nl2br(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['IntroText']), '<i><b>'))."</p>
<hr>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>";
}
```

I have been using this coding philosophy for all my hobby sites for a long time, but I'm self taught old school so probably made a basic mistake somewhere

The site in question is absolutegamerz dot com

And yet this is not a problem on my other site absoluteavp dot com

The hosting provider seem to have HSTS enabled on their nginx as the STS expire is set

Comment: post the whole code

Comment: you need to post all relevant code, even the possible mysql and db schema/values.

Comment: if you logged out of Stack, you're not going to get a solution when you do log back in; not for what you left and didn't post in your question.

Comment: Hey all, been busy tilling the downstairs toilet. I've added the extra info into the original post (see bottom half)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was simple type-o, and a strange rewrite rule on the server.

I contacted by host provider, they were of little help.

I started to go back to fundamentals and check the network traffic using the developer tool in the browser.

I created a blank html page and started to copy&pase bits of the PHP generated content to see when the problem occurred..........................

....

....

....

in the `<HEADER>` the `<base href="https://.... >` tag caused everything to redirect to HTTPS! d'Oh !!!!!

Then the server had a rewrite rule to send everything back to HTTP and that when the duplication occurred.

Correction of the  tag solved everything

**nOOb** mistake